# Rest API Fetching details

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a major requirement from my manager and this needs to be fulfilled as early as possible.

Requirement: There is a List A and List B. List A acts as a database from which data has to be fetched into List B.

Now List A has three Columns :

1. Business Unit(BU)(Dropdown)
2. Project Name(Textfield)
3. Should Cost Modeler(People Picker Field)

Now, i want to get all my projects based on Business Unit and then when i select a particular project it should fetch employee name in regard to the project.

Example : If in List B i select a Bu : Xyz , then all the projects pertaining to the BU should pop up and then as soon as i select project name, the should cost modeler name should be in dropdown.

How do i fulfill this requirement. As it is a very tricky one and i am not so good in Rest API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To filter based on BU, sample rest api `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectMaster')/items?$filter=Business_x0020_Unit eq 'HR'`

Select user name and filter based on Project Name `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectMaster')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler&$filter=Project_x0020_Name eq 'p1'`

[Common Dropdown operation](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/02/common-dropdown-operation-get-set-add.html)

Comment: i would want all the BU in the dropdown and then on selection of one BU i would want all the projects related to that BU

Comment: You could check this demo https://birenpanigrahi.blogspot.com/2017/01/get-distinct-values-of-column-from.html to get all BU and then binding to dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To Get All Bussiness Unit from Choice column(Dropdown) use this ajax call.

```
$.ajax({

    url: "host url"+"_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('List Name')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'Choice Field Name'",

    type: "GET",

    headers: {

        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",

    },

    success: function (data) {

        console.log(data.d.results[0].Choices.results);

    },

    error: function (error) {

        alert(JSON.stringify(error));

    }

});
```

then use rest API suggested by @Lee_MSFT.

> To filter based on BU, sample rest api /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectMaster')/items?$filter=Business_x0020_Unit eq 'HR'
>
> Select user name and filter based on Project Name /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ProjectMaster')/items?$select=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler/Title&$expand=Should_x0020_Cost_x0020_Modeler&$filter=Project_x0020_Name eq 'p1'